# How to Create Framework-Dependent Executables with .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

How do I create framework-dependent executables (FDE) with .NET Core 2.2? The MSDN documentation mentions them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) as a new feature for .NET Core 2.2:

> Framework-dependent executables (FDE)
>
> Starting with .NET Core 2.2, you
>   can deploy your app as an FDE, along with any required third-party
>   dependencies. Your app will use the version of .NET Core that's
>   installed on the target system.

Sadly the step-by-step examples still only refer to self-contained and framework-dependent deployments (FDD).

Comment: You might want to vote here: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9728.

Comment: @Patrick Will certainly do that, although I'd love to get an answer a bit quicker than it takes to get that issue resolved :-) You don't happen to have a link to the github issue that implemented FDEs? Can't find it, but I assume I could figure out how to do what I want from there.

Comment: And more stuff to read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/) on .NET Core 3, where "Applications now have executables by default".

Comment: No, unfortunately I have to revert to using Google here.

Comment: @Patrick Afraid that the .NET Core 3 stuff is really just for 3.0. Building it with 2.2 doesn't result in a exe but still only a dll without dependencies. But yes also googling to see if I can find something - will answer my question if I can figure it out (or get ahold of someone who knows)

Comment: I know, but it might be worth reading up on that since it might fix your issue in the future, or provide with some pointers how to go forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### .NET Core 2.2

The way to do this is to specify a runtime identifier and then `--self-contained false`:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

This will generate an executable without including the whole .NET Core framework.

### .NET Core 3.0

For .NET Core 3.0 the following can be used:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --no-self-contained
```

Comment: *Note:* This question is for .NET Core 2.2 but the new way with .NET Core 3.0 is to use the `--no-self-contained` flag instead of `--self-contained false`

Comment: @Jérôme Fair enough to keep this up to date. I don't have a dotnet core 3.0 project in front of me right now, but I'd assume the edit should work correctly?

Comment: I tested with .NET Core 3.0, actually both ways work. Yes your edit is correct