# Publish .NET Core 2.2 app in Visual Studio 2017 as framework-dependent executable (FDE)

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publish

According to Microsoft, as of .NET Core 2.2 I can publish an app as a "framework-dependent executable" (FDE).  It works from the command-line [using the `dotnet` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075899/2704659):

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

However, I'd like to do it using the GUI tool in Visual Studio (2017), where I can configure and store a profile:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a `Target Runtime`.  The UI is a little confusing and doesn't use the phrase `framework-dependent executable`.

[image]